Countries that revoke citizenship obtained at birth because of retroactive revocation of a parent's citizenship
Suppose a person was born with citizenship of country X because at least one parent had citizenship of country X at the time of their birth.
Now, suppose that, after the person's birth, it's discovered that the parent had committed fraud during the citizenship process or otherwise failed to meet all the conditions to become a citizen. As a result, the parent's citizenship is revoked. Are there any countries that also revoke the citizenship of the child under these circumstances?
For example, in United States law, the revocation of naturalization for fraud (or other failure to satisfy the criteria for naturalization) is considered to be retroactive to the date of the naturalization (8 USC 1451), creating a legal fiction that the person was never naturalized in the first place. In that case, would any of their children who were born outside the US and were US citizens at birth also have their citizenship voided on the basis that, in the rewritten version of history, they had no US citizen parent at the time of birth?
As I understand it, this is an unresolved question in US law, but I would like to know whether there are any countries that do, in fact, revoke citizenship of the child, who had citizenship from birth, because their parent's citizenship was revoked with retroactive effect?
Or, the opposite: are there any countries where, when a person commits fraud during the naturalization process, the naturalization is granted, and is later revoked because the fraud is discovered, the policy is explicitly that such revocation is not retroactive? Or, where the revocation is retroactive, but the policy is that it does not affect the children who were born with citizenship?

IIRC, John Demjanjuk's daughter (who wasn't born in the US) retained her US citizenship when her father's was revoked retroactively due to the immigration fraud (omitting his war-criminal past).

@littleadv Assuming that the mother was also a US citizen, it seems possible that their daughter could have obtained citizenship at birth solely by descent from her. And it is not clear whether there is any legal basis to revoke the mother's citizenship.

It's unclear if his wife was in fact her mother since according to Wikipedia John met Vera Kowlowa in 1951, whereas Lidyia was born in 1950.

@littleadv This source says that he met Vera in 1945: https://www.cleveland.com/metro/2012/03/seven_hills_john_demjanjuk_con.html

The USA
As you say, the revocation of US citizenship is retroactive meaning that, if the child would not become stateless, they would never have been a US citizen. The US has adopted the UN Conventions against Statelessness which means that the US government cannot take an action that would render a person stateless.
For the converse, Australia
Revocation of citizenship on the basis of fraud is not retroactive, so the child would retain Australian citizenship.

I think this answer needs some additional sources regarding the US. Although revocation of naturalization is retroactive in the US, it is not clear just from the text of the law what the retroactiveness applies to. For example, the Supreme Court has ruled that, if a person committed a crime after naturalization, that would result in deportation for a non-citizen, it does not make the person deportable if the naturalization is later rescinded. Costello v. INS, 376 U.S. 120 (1964)

Regarding Australia, section 36 of that law seems to say that children under the age of 18 also lose their citizenship (but it's not retroactive to their birth).

@Brian No, s36 gives discretion to revoke the citizenship. It’s also subject to the no statelessness rule.
